# What build to submit to itunes connect

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ads

I'm using google AdMobs in my iOS game. The problem is that I removed the test ads from the code one day before uploading the build to itunesConnect. Now the AdMobs account is suspended for violating the terms of service. I have also pulled the build from itunesConnect. My question is what build to submit exactly. One with the real ads or one with the test ads. Google also said that further violations during the 30 day suspension period will result in a permanent ban and I really want to avoid this. So what is the common practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge i used Admob in my iOS application since long time. Probably you need to take care about following steps.

- Be careful you used test ad during your app is in development mode.
- When you going to live this application you should remove test.device line code and also check two time you are replace individual Ad id with test id.
- Never click on advertisement either development mode and after live application at your end.
- Do not used Admob for any sexual contain app that consider as a violations so you strick take care about this step.

[Note As par Ad Mob doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start)

[image]

Comment: "When you going to live this application you should remove test.device line code and also check two time you are replace individual Ad id with test id." Dont you mean replace test ID with Ad id ?

Comment: see in adMob you need to create app for your indivudial app Ad id right. each app need to create it's uniq app id at admob end. so you need to put read Ad id instead of test id durint live your app

Comment: yes I already have created a ID for the banner ad I'm displaying. But I have never used a test ID. The only thing I have use is the test device code during development. So you are saying that I should submit a build to apple with the real ads and not a test device ?

Comment: yes ofcorce that test device line for developer. so we can check that ad is appear proper or not during development mode. when you submit build you dont need this testdevice code.